# How to change CloudKit displayName in system setting page?

Tags: cloudkit

My App is still developing, I can't find anywhere to change CloudKit container's displayName.. Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses your app's display name for this iCloud setting. This is not the same thing as your CloudKit container identifier (which is usually something like `iCloud.com.CartDataSync` anyway).

To change this, go to your project settings in Xcode, select your iOS target, and then change the **Display Name** at the top.

If that doesn't affect it, in Xcode go to your **Build Settings** > **Packaging** > **Product Name** and see if you are overriding the default name there.